# Getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift3, uilabel, mapkit, mkannotationview

MapPinAnnotation is a class of MKAnnotation type in which I have defined

```
var lblNotificationCount:UILabel!
```

I want to set text at label but getting error as described below: -

```
let storeAnnotation = annotation as! MapPinAnnotation
```

[image]

and in console i am able to get value of count but it print error as below: -

Console Output:

```
Count: 1
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Please help, how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: .text = String(count) ... try

Comment: @cerberus, Not working.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
storeAnnotation.lblNotificationCount.text = String(describing: count)
```

Comment: Still getting same error. Not working.

Comment: do check IBOutlet for your label.